# Proving $mn \leq p < (n + 1)m$

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying an intro analysis book, and I have come across this problem:

> Show that if $m \in \mathbb R^+$, then for each $p \in \mathbb R$, there is $n \in \mathbb Z$ for which $mn \leq p < (n + 1)m$.

I have started the problem by proving the first inequality i.e. $p \geq mn$. My intuition is that the proof must have the same flavour as the proof of the Archimedean property. So my aim so far has been to claim that if there is an $n \in \mathbb Z$ satisfying $mn > p$, then there "must" be an $n$ satisfying its negation (that is, the side of the inequality I wish to prove). But I know that this isn't particularly rigorous at all, and I was wondering if I could get some help on it.

Comment: The problems in your heading and in the body of the question are totally different.

Comment: Oh I was being too loose. Is it understandable now?

Comment: This is not true for $m=1, p=-1$.

Comment: I have incorrectly transcribed the problem. Apologies; it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your integer $n$ satisfies:
$$
n\leq (p/m)<n+1
$$
Have you heard of the floor function ($\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$)? The least upper bound property of $\mathbb{R}$ is useful.

Comment: Oh great! I have completed the proof. Thank you!